# Create sentence with data from two different objects

Tags: concatenation, sentence

Based on this data:

```
const employees = {
   employee1: {name: "Susana", age: 54}, 
   employee2: {name: "Mariano", age: 55}
}

const companies = { 
   company1: {name: "General Electric"},
   company2: {name: "Apple Computers"}
};
```

I need to create a sentence that looks like:

```
Susana works at General Electric
```

Since both objects use the value `name` (and I am not allowed to change them), I have *no* idea how to concatenate both to create a coherent sentence. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
const createSentence = function (name, company) {

   let nombre = employees.employee1['name'];
   let compania = companies.company1['name'];

   return console.log(nombre + " works at " + compania);
}

createSentence(); // "Susana works at General Electric"
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your code as well.